# Centering diagrams made with tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I used tikzcd in equation environment so that the diagram should be placed on a new line and centered but I don't know why it is not perfectly centered.
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows}
\begin{document}
The diagram is not perfectly centered:
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
H^0(U\cup V) \rar & H^0(U)\oplus H^0(V) \rar & H^0(U\cap V) 
\ar[out=-20, in=160]{dll} \\
H^1(U\cup V) \rar & H^1(U)\oplus H^1(V)\rar & H^1(U\cap V) 
\ar[out=-20, in=160]{dll} \\
H^2(U\cup V) \rar & H^2(U)\oplus H^2(V)\rar & H^2(U\cap V) 
\end{tikzcd} 
\]
\end{document}
```

The diagram appears slightly on the right side of the page. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Put this in the preamble.  \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}  This will make all margins equal 1 in, resulting in a centered diagram.  Now you need to read the manual for 'geometry" at http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/geometry/geometry.pdf.  In this well written documentation you will learn about the page layout and discover that geometry provide you will many useful options to control the layout.

Comment: @R.Schumacher The horizontal margins are symmetric in a standard `article`, making them narrower might by accident solve the problem, but fixing the actual cause (see my answer) is certainly better.

Comment: @Torbjorn +1 Great answer and I learned something I had missed about Tikz diagrams

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason for this is that the curved arrows define helper coordinates that are placed far outside the drawn parts of the diagram, so the diagram contains a lot of whitespace, and its width is actually wider than the width of the text block. Look in the log and you'll see a warning about an `Overfull \hbox (72.53682pt too wide)`. To visualize this, add the `backgrounds` TikZ library, and add `[show background rectangle]` to the options of the `tikzcd` environment. (See code below.)

To fix it, add `overlay` to the options of the `\ar` commands that draws the arrow. This option means that those commands will not be taken into account when the bounding box of the diagram is defined.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
The diagram is not perfectly centered:
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[show background rectangle]
H^0(U\cup V) \rar & H^0(U)\oplus H^0(V) \rar & H^0(U\cap V) 
\ar[out=-20, in=160]{dll} \\
H^1(U\cup V) \rar & H^1(U)\oplus H^1(V)\rar & H^1(U\cap V) 
\ar[out=-20, in=160]{dll} \\
H^2(U\cup V) \rar & H^2(U)\oplus H^2(V)\rar & H^2(U\cap V) 
\end{tikzcd} 
\]
The diagram is centered:
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[show background rectangle]
H^0(U\cup V) \rar & H^0(U)\oplus H^0(V) \rar & H^0(U\cap V) 
\ar[overlay,out=-20, in=160]{dll} \\
H^1(U\cup V) \rar & H^1(U)\oplus H^1(V)\rar & H^1(U\cap V) 
\ar[overlay,out=-20, in=160]{dll} \\
H^2(U\cup V) \rar & H^2(U)\oplus H^2(V)\rar & H^2(U\cap V) 
\end{tikzcd} 
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

No such problem for a commutative diagram made with `pstricks`. Loading `auto-pst-pdf` enables you to compile with `pdflatex`, provided it is launched with the `-shell-escape`switch (TeX Live, MacTeX) or `--enable-write18`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}%
\usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}%

\begin{document}

\[\begin{psmatrix}[rowsep =5ex]
    H^0(U \cup V) & H^0(U) \oplus H^0(V) & H^0(U \cap V)\pnode[0,0.15]{S1}\\
    \pnode[0,0.08]{S2}H^1(U \cup V) & H^1(U) \oplus H^1(V) & H^1(U \cap V)\pnode[0,0.15]{S3} \\
    \pnode[0,0.08]{S4}H^2(U \cup V) & H^2(U) \oplus H^2(V) & H^2(U \cap V)
    \psset{arrows=->, linewidth=0.5pt, nodesep=4pt, arrowinset=0.12}
    \ncline{1,1}{1,2}\ncline{1,2}{1,3}
    \ncline{2,1}{2,2}\ncline{2,2}{2,3}
    \ncline{3,1}{3,2}\ncline{3,2}{3,3}
    \psset{angleA=-15,angleB=165, ncurv=0.8, nodesepB=2pt}
    \nccurve[angleA=-15,angleB=165, ncurv=0.8, nodesepB=2pt]{S1}{S2}%{1,3}{2,1}
    \nccurve{S3}{S4}
  \end{psmatrix}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]