# Tikz-cd and the Mayer-Vietoris sequence

Tags: diagrams, tikz-cd

In this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115002/which-package-should-i-use-for-doing-a-connecting-homomorphism-diagram-like-this/115020) I have found a very useful answer to made the Mayer-Vietoris sequence for homology using `tikz-cd`. However, I need some help creating a diagram like this:
[image: The Mayer-Vietoris sequence for cohomology]

I want to draw it using the same package, but I cannot modify correctly the code given in the post to draw the reverse arrow for the connecting homomorphism. This is the code that I have tried to modify, but have had no success.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzset{
  curarrow/.style={
  rounded corners=8pt,
  execute at begin to={every node/.style={fill=red}},
    to path={-- ([xshift=50pt]\tikztostart.center)
    |- (#1) node[fill=white] {$\scriptstyle d^*$}
    -| ([xshift=-50pt]\tikztotarget.center)
    -- (\tikztotarget)}
    }
}

\begin{document}

   \begin{tikzcd}[arrow style=math font,cells={nodes={text height=2ex,text depth=0.75ex}}]
       H^{k+1}(M) \arrow[r, "i^{*}"] & H^{k+1}(U) \oplus H^{k+1}(V) \arrow[r] & \cdots \\
       H^{k}(M) \arrow[r, "i^{*}"] & H^{k}(U) \oplus H^{k}(V) \arrow[r, "j^{*}"] \arrow[draw=none]{u}[name=Y, shape=coordinate]{} \arrow[draw=none]{d}[name=Z,shape=coordinate]{} & H^{k}(U \cap V) \arrow[curarrow=Y]{ull}{} \\
       \cdots \arrow[r] & H^{k-1}(U) \oplus H^{k-1}(V) \arrow[r, "j^{*}"] & H^{k-1}(U \cap V) \arrow[curarrow=Z]{ull}{}
   \end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344489/centering-diagrams-made-with-tikz-cd

Comment: So the code compiled for you? I get an error `! Package pgf Error: No shape named tikz@f@1-0-7 is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help
...
l.160 I think the culprit is a tikzcd arrow in cell 1-7.
\errmessage ...currentrow -\tikzcd@currentcolumn }
                                                  
l.164 \end{tikzcd}` from the only code there that seems to use `tikz-cd`. How did you resolve it? Or did it compile for you?

Comment: You didn't actually try even compiling the code which was there as is, did you? Let alone attempt to modify it?

Comment: @cfr I compiled the code and it worked fine for me, using pdflatex for my latex file. I have edited the post to add the code that I tried to modify.

Comment: You have now, but you didn't before posting your question. I posted that code after posting my comments here and fixing the original in the answer to the question you linked. That code can't be what you said you'd tried to modify because the code was only available after I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a working modification of the code block you posted:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzset{
  curarrow/.style={
  rounded corners=8pt,
  execute at begin to={every node/.style={fill=red}},
    to path={-- ([xshift=-50pt]\tikztostart.center)
    |- (#1) node[fill=white] {$\scriptstyle d_*$}
    -| ([xshift=50pt]\tikztotarget.center)
    -- (\tikztotarget)}
    }
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzcd}[arrow style=math font,cells={nodes={text height=2ex,text depth=0.75ex}}]
       \cdots & H_{k-1}(U) \oplus H_{k-1}(V) \arrow[l] \arrow[draw=none]{d}[name=Y, shape=coordinate]{} & \arrow[l] H_{k-1}(U \cap V) \\
       H_{k}(M) \arrow[curarrow=Y]{urr}{} & H_{k}(U) \oplus H_{k}(V) \arrow[l] \arrow[draw=none]{d}[name=Z,shape=coordinate]{} & H_{k}(U \cap V) \arrow[l] \\
       H_{k+1}(M) \arrow[curarrow=Z]{urr}{} & H_{k+1}(U) \oplus H_{k+1}(V) \arrow[l] & \cdots \arrow[l]
   \end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The changes I made:

- in the code block you posted, following the middle middle position `H^{k}(U) \oplus H^{k}(V)`, there were two coordinate-setting arrows

  `\arrow[draw=none]{u}[name=Y, shape=coordinate]{} \arrow[draw=none]{d}[name=Z,shape=coordinate]{}`

  These coordinates are used to set the position of the boundary map labels: the Y coordinate is set between the middle middle and middle top (via an upward pointing arrow), and the Z coordinate is set between the middle middle and middle bottom (via a downward pointing arrow). I want to send an arrow from the middle left to the upper right, but the coordinate Y must be defined before I use it, so I moved the definition to the middle top, pointing down to the middle middle.
- I modified the definition of the `curarrow` style slightly. In the original, the path starts by moving to the *right* by 50pt, turning around, then overshooting to the *left* by 50pt before ending; these are reflected in the `xshift`s. Since the orientation of the arrow is reversed, I reversed the signs on the `xshift`s to reflect the change.
- Obviously the arrows are reversed. Since the original code block produced Mayer-Vietoris for cohomology and the arrows have been reversed, I also took the liberty of switching the groups to homology groups. This is probably not what you wanted, sorry.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly fine for me and it's exactly what I wanted. Very good explanation of the changes made in the original code. Now I can understand why my modified code was not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain this diagram with `pstricks` and a `psmatrix` environment. For the connecting homomorphism, I add  intermediate empty nodes at each end, between consecutives rows, and connect them with a composite path:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node,  auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

 \[  \def\psrowhookiii{\psset{mrow=r}}
  \begin{psmatrix}[rowsep=1.35]
  \pnode[-0.5,0]{A}\\
  \pnode[1,1]{A2}H^{q+1}_c(M) & H^{q + 1}_c(U) \oplus H^{q + 1}_c(V) & H^{q + 1}_c(U \cap V)\pnode[0,-0.8]{B2}\\
   \pnode[0,1]{A3}  H^q_c(M) & H^q_c(U) \oplus H^q_c(V) & H^q_c(U \cap V)\pnode[-1,-0.8]{B3}\\
       & &   \pnode{B}
       \psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0.12, nodesep=4pt,  linearc=0.4}
       \ncline{2,3}{2,2} \ncline{2,2}{2,1}\ncbar[angle=180, ]{2,1}{A2}%
       \ncbar[arm=0.7, angle=180, arrows=-, nodesepB=0]{3,1}{A3}\ncline[arrows=-, nodesep=0]{A3}{B2}\nbput[labelsep=1.5pt]{d^*}%
       \ncbar[arm=0.76, angle=0, arrows=->, nodesepA=0]{B2}{2,3}%
       \ncline{3,3}{3,2} \ncline{3,2}{3,1}\ncbar[arm=0.76, angle=0, arrows=->, nodesepA=0]{B3}{3,3}%
    \end{psmatrix} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The diagram is perfect, but I get an error when I compile the code using pdflatex.

Comment: Oh! yes, of course. You have to add the compiler  switch `--enable-write18` if you're under MiKTeX, or `-shell-escape` for TeX Live and MacTeX. Alternatively, don't load `auto-pst-pdf` and compile with `xelatex`.